# Where is located on Mac the mpv player configuration file?

Tags: macos, mpv

This excellent player works on Mac, but while in Linux I can set shortkeys and such in ~/.config/mpv/input.conf, I don`t know where that is on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~ means exactly the same thing on Mac (it's Unix, after all) as it does on Linux: $HOME

Specifically this will be at `/Users/username` rather than `/home/username`, but that doesn't change the relevant commands.
If the dir doesn't exist yet then all you need to do is create it.

`mkdir -p ~/.config/mpv` then copy your mpv.conf and input.conf.